# When using dual monitors, left monitor uses 1024x768 and right monitor uses 1920x720. Why its slow?

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, video, display, monitor

I have one PC where I have my main screen using 1024x768 resolution and my another screen using 1980x720 resolution.

But why its so slow, is there any way to make it faster like normal?

I had the same issue with Fedora 15 like now I have with Ubuntu.

**Follow up:**

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

$ export DISPLAY=:0.0 && glxinfo | grep -i direct
direct rendering: Yes
```

Comment: Are you using any proprietary graphic drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if:
a) Your OS sees Your graphic card, and identifies it properly:

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

b) You have hardware acceleration enabled:

```
glxinfo | grep -i direct
```

Please give the output of those two in Your question.
(if You do not have glxifno install mesa utils:)

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Regards

Comment: @Milsery: edited as above.

Comment: Hmmm... well it looks like Your VGA card works well. In the latest Ubuntu with Unity I had the same issue, it worked very slow. Which verion of ubuntu do You use? And one more thing: is Your VGA card powerful enough to work on the settings You have (resolution, 3d effects etc.)?

Comment: With out dual head, it works perfect with effects and video test etc. But once its dual head and random resolution it start happening that slowness, i have same with (Fedora 15 before). I am using Ubuntu 11.04 (GNU/Linux 2.6.38-8-generic x86_64).

Comment: Try to set very small resolution on both screens. Does it help?

Comment: Yes small resolution works even it works when i use same resolution small in both. But big and small does not fit makes it very slow.

Comment: It looks like Your card has not enough 'power' to work in such resolution on both monitors. First please check if You have enabled all required options in BIOS - check Your mainboard or VGA card manual for details. (search for options like surround view, dual monitor support etc.) BE CAREFUL WHILE CHANGING ANYTHING IN BIOS. One more thing that comes to my mind is to check frequency on which Your monitors work

Comment: you have selected this answer as the best answer, but what did you do to solve the issue finally ? a BIOS or frequency modification ? could you add it in the answer please